How to return columns from dynamic SQL in Python console
I'm trying to make a CRUD application that uses Oracle procedures for the operations.
For the READ component, I wrote a procedure that returns one or more entire rows depending on the specified attributes. It works correctly on Oracle SQL Developer, but I can't get the data to display once I'm in Python.
This is the READ portion of the Python app:
def verEmpleado():
    opcionCorrecta = False
    while(not opcionCorrecta):
        print('================= CONSULTA =================')
        print('[1] Employee ID')
        print('[2] Employee name')
        print('[3] Job')
        print('[4] Manager')
        print('[5] Hire date')
        print('[6] Salary')
        print('[7] Commission')
        print('[8] Department ID')
        print('============================================')

        command = int(input('Seleccione la columna: '))
        match command:
            case 1:
                p_filter_att = 'empno'
                opcionCorrecta = True
            case 2:
                p_filter_att = 'ename'
                opcionCorrecta = True
            case 3:
                p_filter_att = 'job'
                opcionCorrecta = True
            case 4:
                p_filter_att = 'mgr'
                opcionCorrecta = True
            case 5:
                p_filter_att = 'hiredate'
                opcionCorrecta = True
            case 6:
                p_filter_att = 'sal'
                opcionCorrecta = True
            case 7:
                p_filter_att = 'comm'
                opcionCorrecta = True
            case 8:
                p_filter_att = 'deptno'
                opcionCorrecta = True
            case _:
                print('Comando incorrecto, intente de nuevo...\n')


    p_value_att = input('Ingrese el valor de la columna a seleccionar: ')

    data = [p_filter_att, p_value_att]
    return data

#CONNECT TO DB
def connVerEmpleado(data):
        try:
            conn = cx_Oracle.connect('HR/hr@localhost:1521/xepdb1')
        except Exception as err:
            print('Excepción al crear la conexión:', err)
        else:
            try:
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.callproc('query_emp', data)

                result = cursor.fetchall()
                print(result)
                cursor.close()

            except Exception as err:
                print('Error al conectar:', err)

This is the procedure
create or replace PROCEDURE query_emp(p_filter_att IN VARCHAR2, p_value_att IN VARCHAR2)
IS
    sql_qry              VARCHAR2(1000);
    TYPE bc_v_empno      IS TABLE OF NUMBER(4);
    v_empno              bc_v_empno;
    TYPE bc_v_ename      IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
    v_ename              bc_v_ename;
    TYPE bc_v_job        IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(9);
    v_job                bc_v_job;
    TYPE bc_v_mgr        IS TABLE OF NUMBER(4);
    v_mgr                bc_v_mgr;
    TYPE bc_v_hiredate   IS TABLE OF DATE;
    v_hiredate           bc_v_hiredate;
    TYPE bc_v_sal        IS TABLE OF NUMBER(7,2);
    v_sal                bc_v_sal;
    TYPE bc_v_comm       IS TABLE OF NUMBER(7,2);
    v_comm               bc_v_comm;
    TYPE bc_v_deptno     IS TABLE OF NUMBER(2);
    v_deptno             bc_v_deptno;
BEGIN
    sql_qry := 'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE ' || p_filter_att || ' = UPPER(:p_value_att)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_qry BULK COLLECT INTO v_empno, v_ename, v_job, v_mgr, v_hiredate, v_sal, v_comm, v_deptno
    USING p_value_att;

    FOR i IN 1..v_empno.COUNT
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line('ID: ' || v_empno(i) || ' | NAME: ' || v_ename(i) || ' | JOB: ' || v_job(i) || ' | MANAGER: ' || v_mgr(i) || ' | HIRE DATE: ' || v_hiredate(i) || ' | SALARY: ' || v_sal(i) || ' | COMMISSION: ' || v_comm(i) || ' | DEPARTMENT: ' || v_deptno(i));
        END LOOP;

END query_emp;
/

When I use fetchall() it returns the error not a query, other methods don't return anything at all.

There's an example of using DBMS_OUTPUT in samples/dbms_output.py. It is also discussed in the documentation Using DBMS_OUTPUT.
However, DBMS_OUTPUT is not the best choice.  Instead, just return a REF CURSOR similar to samples/ref_cursor.py. The documentation for this is at REF CURSOR Bind Variables.
From the doc, if you create a PL/SQL procedure like:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE find_employees (
    p_query IN VARCHAR2,
    p_results OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_results FOR
        SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name
        FROM employees
        WHERE UPPER(first_name || ' ' || last_name || ' ' || email)
            LIKE '%' || UPPER(p_query) || '%';
END;
/

then you can call it in Python like:
ref_cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.callproc("find_employees", ['Smith', ref_cursor])
for row in ref_cursor:
    print(row)


Thank you! The example in the documentation helped, but I'll check out the REF CURSOR information

The REF CURSOR solution should be used for various reason.  Also you tagged the question "cx-oracle".  It's time to upgrade from cx_Oracle to python-oracledb.

Don't print the output to a console in the database. Create a cursor and return that.
CREATE PROCEDURE query_emp(
  p_filter_att IN  VARCHAR2,
  p_value_att  IN  VARCHAR2,
  p_results    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
  v_handle PLS_INTEGER;
  v_rows   PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  v_handle := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
 
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(
    v_handle,
    'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE ' || p_filter_att || ' = UPPER(:value)',
    DBMS_SQL.NATIVE
  );
  DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(v_handle, 'value', p_value_att);
  v_rows := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(v_handle);

  p_results := DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR(v_handle);
END query_emp;
/

Then call it in Python and read from the cursor:
#CONNECT TO DB
def connVerEmpleado(data):
    try:
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect('HR/hr@localhost:1521/xepdb1')
    except Exception as err:
        print('Excepción al crear la conexión:', err)
    else:
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            result_cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.callproc('query_emp', [*data, result_cursor])
            print(result_cursor)
            cursor.close()
        except Exception as err:
            print('Error al conectar:', err)

Note: Python code is untested.
